# OpenGL Batch Rendering issue

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, rendering

Im attempting to create a 3D Block Batch renderer following TheChernoProject's tutorials, however i've run into quite a problem : Nothing is being rendered on the screen. When i switch back to the default renderer, I.E for-each VAO{BIND, DRAW, UNBIND} everything is fine.
Here is the code (Heavily commented because it's messy)

BatchRenderer:

```
public class BatchRenderer {

public static final int MAX_BLOCKS_PER_CALL = 10000;
public static final int INDICES_SIZE        = MAX_BLOCKS_PER_CALL * 36;
public static final int VERTEX_SIZE         = 3 * Float.BYTES;
private int             indices_count       = 0;

//creating a ByteBuffer to store all submitted vertices : 24 verts per block * 12 bytes per Vector3f * MAX_BLOCKS_PER_CALL
private ByteBuffer      buffer              = MemoryUtil.memAlloc(24 * VERTEX_SIZE * MAX_BLOCKS_PER_CALL);
//fb to store data more simple
private FloatBuffer     fBuffer;

private int             vbo;
private int             vao;

private IndexBuffer     ibo;

public BatchRenderer() {
    init();
}

public void init() {
    vao = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
    vbo = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.capacity(), GL15.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    int[] indices = new int[INDICES_SIZE];

    //The next ~40 lines make sure that every added block has its own 24 indices linked to the vertices
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < INDICES_SIZE; i += 36) {
        indices[i] = offset + 1;
        indices[i + 1] = offset + 3;
        indices[i + 2] = offset + 0;
        indices[i + 3] = offset + 7;
        indices[i + 4] = offset + 5;
        indices[i + 5] = offset + 4;
        indices[i + 6] = offset + 8;
        indices[i + 7] = offset + 9;
        indices[i + 8] = offset + 10;
        indices[i + 9] = offset + 11;
        indices[i + 10] = offset + 2;
        indices[i + 11] = offset + 12;
        indices[i + 12] = offset + 6;
        indices[i + 13] = offset + 13;
        indices[i + 14] = offset + 14;
        indices[i + 15] = offset + 15;
        indices[i + 16] = offset + 16;
        indices[i + 17] = offset + 17;
        indices[i + 18] = offset + 1;
        indices[i + 19] = offset + 18;
        indices[i + 20] = offset + 3;
        indices[i + 21] = offset + 7;
        indices[i + 22] = offset + 19;
        indices[i + 23] = offset + 5;
        indices[i + 24] = offset + 8;
        indices[i + 25] = offset + 20;
        indices[i + 26] = offset + 9;
        indices[i + 27] = offset + 11;
        indices[i + 28] = offset + 21;
        indices[i + 29] = offset + 2;
        indices[i + 30] = offset + 6;
        indices[i + 31] = offset + 22;
        indices[i + 32] = offset + 13;
        indices[i + 33] = offset + 15;
        indices[i + 34] = offset + 23;
        indices[i + 35] = offset + 16;
        offset += 24;
    }
    ibo = new IndexBuffer(indices);
    indices_count = 0;
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}

public void begin() {
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    //Creates the buffer mapping 
    buffer = GL15.glMapBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL15.GL_WRITE_ONLY, buffer.capacity(), buffer);
    fBuffer = buffer.asFloatBuffer();
}

public void end() {
    GL15.glUnmapBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

}

public void submit(Block b) {
    Vector3f bPos = b.getPosition();
    float x = bPos.x;
    float y = bPos.y;
    float z = bPos.z;
    //The next ~25 lines put the block's vertices added to the submitted block's position
    fBuffer.put(0.985088f + x).put(0.996634f + y).put(-0.986804f + z);
    fBuffer.put(0.985088f + x).put(0.996634f + y).put(1.013196f + z);
    fBuffer.put(-1.014912f + x).put(0.996634f + y).put(1.013196f + z);
    fBuffer.put(-1.014912f + x).put(0.996634f + y).put(-0.986805f + z);
    fBuffer.put(0.985088f + x).put(2.996634f + y).put(-0.986804f + z);
    fBuffer.put(0.985087f + x).put(2.996634f + y).put(1.013196f + z);
    fBuffer.put(-1.014913f + x).put(2.996634f + y).put(1.013196f + z);
    fBuffer.put(-1.014912f + x).put(2.996634f + y).put(-0.986804f + z);
    fBuffer.put(0.985088f + x).put(2.996634f + y).put(-0.986804f + z);
    fBuffer.put(0.985088f + x).put(0.996634f + y).put(1.013196f + z);
    fBuffer.put(0.985088f + x).put(0.996634f + y).put(-0.986804f + z);
    fBuffer.put(0.985087f + x).put(2.996634f + y).put(1.013196f + z);
    fBuffer.put(0.985088f + x).put(0.996634f + y).put(1.013196f + z);
    fBuffer.put(-1.014912f + x).put(0.996634f + y).put(-0.986805f + z);
    fBuffer.put(-1.014912f + x).put(0.996634f + y).put(1.013196f + z);
    fBuffer.put(0.985088f + x).put(0.996634f + y).put(-0.986804f + z);
    fBuffer.put(-1.014912f + x).put(2.996634f + y).put(-0.986804f + z);
    fBuffer.put(0.985088f + x).put(2.996634f + y).put(-0.986804f + z);
    fBuffer.put(-1.014912f + x).put(0.996634f + y).put(1.013196f + z);
    fBuffer.put(-1.014913f + x).put(2.996634f + y).put(1.013196f + z);
    fBuffer.put(0.985087f + x).put(2.996634f + y).put(1.013196f + z);
    fBuffer.put(-1.014913f + x).put(2.996634f + y).put(1.013196f + z);
    fBuffer.put(-1.014912f + x).put(2.996634f + y).put(-0.986804f + z);
    fBuffer.put(-1.014912f + x).put(0.996634f + y).put(-0.986805f + z);
    indices_count += 36;
}

public void flush() {
    //draw calls here
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    ibo.bind();
    GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, indices_count, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    ibo.unbind();
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    indices_count = 0;
}

}
```

The method issuing render submissions :

```
Context.openLoop(() -> {
        shader.start();
        cam.update();
        Matrix4f modelViewMatrix = Maths.createPerspectiveMatrix(cam);
        shader.uniformMat4f(shader.location_viewMatrix, modelViewMatrix);
        batchRenderer.begin();
        for (Chunk c : chunks) {
            if (Maths.distance(cam.getPosition(), c.getPosition()) < 300) {
                for (Block b : c.getBlocks()) {
                    if (b == null)
                        continue;
                    if (ViewFrustum.cubeInFrustum(b.getPosition())) {
                        batchRenderer.submit(b);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        batchRenderer.end();
        batchRenderer.flush();
        shader.stop();
    });
```